# How do we prove this convergence of sequence by definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that sequence $a_n = \sqrt{n^2 + 2n}- n$ converges to 1, using the ε-N definition.

I have tried to do it the usual way, getting to the inequality:

$$|\sqrt{n^2 + 2n} - n - 1| < ε$$

but I don't know what to do next; the inside will not always be positive. I'm completely new to these proofs so I would also be happy if you can give me some general tips for proving convergences by ε-N definition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use a following formula: $$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = {a-b\over \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$

So in your case: $$|\sqrt{n^2 + 2n} - n - 1| = \Big|{n^2+2n-(n+1)^2\over \sqrt{n^2 + 2n} +n + 1}\Big|$$

$$ = {1\over \sqrt{n^2 + 2n} +n + 1}<{1\over 2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ (a_n-1)\cdot(\sqrt{n^2+2n}+n+1)=(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-(n+1))(\sqrt{n^2+2n}+(n+1))=(n^2+2n)-(n+1)^2=-1$$
and that $$\sqrt{n^2+2n}+n+1>2n, $$
so $$|a_n-1|<\frac1{2n}. $$

Comment: As a matter of fact, $n\lt\sqrt{n^2+2n}\lt n+1$, which gives upper and lower bounds.